# How should we tag version-dependent questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some questions apply to functionality present only in (or after) certain versions.  Others are for legacy versions such as 5.2.

- By what criteria should tags be applied?
- What tag format(s) should be used?

  - [version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8)
  - [mathematica-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica-7)
  - [v5.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v5.2)
  - [v8.0+](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v8.0%2b)
  - [legacy-pre-v6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy-pre-v6)
  - etc., etc.

Comment: Mr.W could you add the featured tag to this, as it is coming up a lot lately?

Comment: See: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/563/what-to-do-when-a-new-version-comes-out-and-renders-questions-obsolete

Comment: There seem to be several minor version tags, e.g. version-9.0.0, that have cropped up, which does not conform to the guidelines below (I take it these are current).  Is the procedure to edit each question, or should synonyms be created?  (Or maybe there already are synonyms.  I'm unclear about how this all works.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks; I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I'm happy to be of assistance, if you'd like it.  Just let me know what I can do.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I appreciate that!  It looks manageable, but I'll let you know if I change my mind. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well I'm ready to accept some help!  I manually processed all the sub-version tags and created appropriate synonyms, but there are still many questions with both the `bugs` tag and a version tag, which does not comply with [(1361)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1361/121).  Would you kindly edit a few of these from time to time, replacing the version tag with a header of [this format](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1611/121)?  I think I've flooded enough of the front page with edits for today however, so wait a day or two to start, if that works for you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I fear a general call for help will result in a mass retagging, which will make the site appear to be only a bug-tracker to any new visitors, if they happen to view the site by the "active" tab.  Also I'd like to make sure the headers are added accurately with requires investing the time to skim comments and answers, and I could see that falling aside in a rush to finish to job all at once.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've done the Qs tagged [tag:bugs] [tag:version-10] except for two.  One has been merged and I cannot edit the tags; in the other case, OP rolled back my edit and did not respond to my query about it.  See [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs+version-10).  It seems a rather large project overall, and I will have less time to spend on it soon.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for all your help!  Surely you have done enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tagging it [mathematica-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica-x) is redundant on a site on Mathematica. Since version 5 is still fairly used by folks (going by questions on SO), I suggest [version-5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-5) through [version-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7) and [pre-version-5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-version-5) for the rest.

I don't see the need for having tags for minor releases and tags for the current & future versions. That might give the impression that the question is applicable *only* to, say, version 8, and not to 9, which will probably not be true for most cases. I can see the use in creating [version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8) when 9 is out and there is a difference between 8 and 9, but not prior to that, merely to differentiate between 8 and previous versions.

I also think that a version specific tag should be added *only* when it is definitely something that's different from the current version. E.g., "How do I plot Sin[x]? I'm using version 7" should not require [version-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7).

Comment: I must agree, [tag:version-x] is verbose enough that it doesn't require little effort to interpret it.

Comment: I agree with version-x as the standard as well.