# Using the version-10 tag

Tags: discussion

I noticed that recently the [version-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-10) tag gets added to many questions which are not unique to v10 in any other way than that they ask about some new-in-10 functionality.

Does this serve any use?

Previously we only used version specific tags for bugs that were present only in a certain version, or when the question was asking for a solution for a non-current version of Mathematica (i.e. only a solution working in 8 is acceptable, not a solution that requires v10 functionality).  Quoting from rm's answer to [How should we tag version-dependent questions?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-should-we-tag-version-dependent-questions) :

> I don't see the need for having tags for ...
>   the current & future versions. That might give the impression that the
>   question is applicable only to, say, version 8, and not to 9, which
>   will probably not be true for most cases. I can see the use in
>   creating version-8 when 9 is out and there is a difference between 8
>   and 9, but not prior to that, merely to differentiate between 8 and
>   previous versions.

I propose that the [version-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-10) be removed from questions which simply deal with v10 functionality.  Those questions and their answers will be just as relevant for v11.

Comment: Agreed. Happy for everyone to clean that up as they see it.

Comment: rm -rf addressed much of this in [(80)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80/121) and we seem to have been following those guidelines for the most part.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that's the post I linked.  The reason I brought this up is that I noticed that people keep adding the v10 tag to questions, e.g. [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65619/12), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61572/12), [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58741/12), [4](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58284/12), [5](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57938/12) and other recent ones from where I removed it today or earlier.

Comment: I tried telling [folks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54648/5) and asking them to [untag](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54613/how-to-get-grid-lines-at-all-log-tick-marks-in-version-10#comment157132_54613) it back when [v10 was released](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=16619389#16619389). Some did, but I guess it just kept growing slowly and I've been really busy of late and only do moderation work. Needless to say, I'm all for removing it from posts that don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

Now making this a votable answer, because the comment had 3 votes:

Could we, then, differentiate between [version-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-10) and a putative [new-in-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-in-10)? Each version introduces new functionality that people want to discuss, and for version 10 especially, it seems worth calling this out as there are a lot of changes to syntax and data structures that may seem surprising to people who haven't had experience with them. The "new-in" tag also would not eventually become obsolete as the "version" tag does if used in this way.

Another argument for the use of a "new-in" tag is that the documentation does not always record which version brought a given change in an existing function, or otherwise this information is removed on the release of the next version. If changes in functionality prompt a question here, we will be able to keep a record of when those changes occurred using the tag.

**Vote up if you are in favor of** [new-in-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-in-x) **tags in addition to the current** [version-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-x) **ones; vote down if not.**